# struct initialization failure

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm having difficulty initializing a struct in code per below.  Can this even be done, or do I really need to memcpy (urg) the 5-character string into the struct?

```
struct MyStruct  
{  
    char x[5];  
};

main(...)  
{  
    const char* MyString = {"mnopq"}; // I understand this is a non-NULL terminated string -  
                                  // it's OK, I just want five character fields in an array

struct MyStruct = {MyString};     // <---This gives warnings below  
}
```

warning: missing braces around initializer
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without cast

If I wrap initializer like:

```
struct MyStruct = {{MyString}};
```

the first warning goes away.  The second warning does not.  And, thus, the struct is not initialized as hoped.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Oops...it's const char* MyString = "mnopq"; (no braces)

Comment: @user654077: Sorry, but your question and your comments contradict each other. If it should be `const char* MyString = "mnopq"`, then it *is* a null-terminated string. Yet, in the code comments you say that it is not. ??? Decide what you want and edit your question. At this time it is a mess.

Answer (score 4):

`"mnopq"` is an array, `const char * MyString` is not.

`struct MyStruct foo = {"abcde"};` will work, whereas your approach converts the *pointer* `MyString` to an integral value and assigns it to the first element of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to fill a char array with a pointer.  MyString is seen as a const char * instead of an array.  Change your type in the structure to const char *x, and it should do the trick.  Also, MyString is actually a NULL terminated string here.  The compiler sets it into memory with the extra NULL byte at the end, then treats MyString like a const char *.

If you do want the char x[5] instead of the const char *, you could initialize in a couple of ways,

```
struct MyStruct ms = {{'m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'}};
```

or you could do

```
struct MyStruct ms = {{ MyString[0], MyString[1], MyString[2], MyString[3], MyString[4]}};
```

The first set of braces is for initializing the struct members, the second set is for initializing the char array members, so each member(char) has to be set individually.

Comment: I edited above to have an identifier. One other thing is that the MyString[index] version will print junk at the end whereas the first version does not (e.g. mnopq¦ah¦)

Comment: Right, because there is no NULL terminator. But there shouldn't be a NULL at the end of the first example either...  I don't think he mentioned using a defined print function to print out the array as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable of the type MyStruct and assign it's x value to that string.
This should work:

```
struct MyStruct {
char x[5];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   struct MyStruct a;
   const char* MyString = "mnop";

   strncpy((a.x), MyString, 5);

   /* 
    *if within the 5 characters you do not have the null char it will 
    * also print garbage
    */
   printf("%s", a.x);

   return 0;
}
```

However you can't assign a pointer to const char to an array of char as they are different types. So you would need to either use char* in the struct or use memcpy / strcpy to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by DavidMFrey is correct and should get credit before mine! However, here's the source code using his answer as I was able to run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct MyStruct  
{  
    char x[5];  
};
int main(void)  
{  
    const char* MyString = "mnopq";
    struct MyStruct foo = {{ MyString[0], MyString[1], MyString[2], MyString[3], MyString[4]}};
    printf("foo.x is: %s\n", foo.x); // outputs: foo.x is: mnopq¦ah¦"

    struct MyStruct ms = {{'m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'}};
    printf("ms.x is: %s\n", ms.x);   // ms.x is: mnopq

    return 0;
}
```